# How can I detect the frame from video streaming that contains the clearest shot of a graffiti on city walls?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, computer-vision, object-detection

I am working on a graffiti detection project. I need to analyze data stream from a camera mounted sideways on a vehicle to identify graffiti on city walls and notify authorities with the single best capture of graffiti and its geolocation, etc.

I am trying to use a ResNet50 model pre-trained on ImageNet using transfer learning for my graffiti image dataset. The classification will be done on an edge device as network connectivity may not be reliable.

Suppose I have a series of frames that have been detected to contain graffiti, as the vehicle goes past it, but I only need to report one image (so not all frames containing graffiti in the series). How can I do that?

Ideally, I would like to report the frame where the camera is perpendicular to the wall. Why perpendicular? I think that images containing the graffiti when the camera is perpendicular to the wall will more clearly show the graffiti.